# How to locate the cause of SqlException 0x80131904 "error converting data type"?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some C# code that interacts with a SqlServer 2012 database. It uses a `SqlDataReader` that has been created based on a large, complicated SQL query.  Imagine something like:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
  "SELECT <a zillion fields>...",
  connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // do something
    }
    reader.NextResult();
}
```

}

When it does a `Read` operation, it throws:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error converting data type varchar to bigint
```

I *think* I've located the culprit.  Is there a way to get more information from the SqlException, in particular, which column/field caused the problem?

To clarify, I can (and did) manually identify a potential problem.  My question is whether I can get SqlServer tell me where the problem is, so I don't have to manually look at a zillion fields.

Comment: Error message is self-explanatory. You try to convert varchar to bigint which is not valid. We _can't_ know more than that without see your work.

Comment: On top - no, this is all that is given by sql server. "problem" is that all data manipulated by one statement is one atomic operation. It could give the original data though - but it does not.

Comment: I added an example to clarify my problem.

Comment: as you say, you think you found the problem.  How hard would it be to eliminate that one column from your list of zillion fields?  Do that, then try the select again.

Comment: Setup a try...catch and then iterate over each column so you can identify the culprit. For example: while ( reader.HasRows )
{
    for( int index = 0; index < reader.FieldCount; index ++ )
    {
        fields[ reader.GetName( index ) ] = reader.GetString( index );
    }    
}

Comment: @Tarzan - Your comment is the closest that I've seen thus far to an answer.  If you convert the comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a try...catch and then iterate over each column so you can identify the culprit. For example:

```
while ( reader.HasRows )    
{

    for( int index = 0; index < reader.FieldCount; index ++ )
    {
        fields[ reader.GetName( index ) ] = reader.GetString( index );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a package?

I would Ctrl+F for items that are Int64 in your code and see where they are being sent to. There is an error in which the input is not the same datatype as the output or vis-versa.  Check the DataSource to make sure that the datatypes line up as well.

Comment: Ctrl+F?  please clarify